# Get a Review Link automatically with Git Push

Tags: git, gerrit

I have done my gerrit server configuration on my server for the first time. In my current set up, I have to follow the following steps

1. git clone [Clone the repo]
2. Some work
3. git commit [Make a commit]
4. git push [Push to branch]
5. git review [Generates review link]

Step no. 4 is optional, as I can directly do a git review and generate the review link.

But if I want to create a review link automatically with my git push, how can I do it as given here :

https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-quick.html#_creating_the_review

Also I see that if I only do git push I cannot see the changes in Gerrit UI.

Have I made any mistake in gerrit configuration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you don't need to execute "git push" and "git review" because git-review is just a tool to help/automate some tasks related to Git/Gerrit (more info [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Gerrit/git-review)).

So, it's totally enought to execute the "git push" command as described in the [documentation link you have posted](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-quick.html#_creating_the_review):

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

If you can't see your change in Gerrit probably there's something wrong with your push command. Have you added the "refs/for/" in your branch name?

Add the output of your push command to the question...

Comment: You are right, I was pushing with git push origin HEAD:refs/HEAD/master instead of git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master. Can you please tell me the difference between the two ?

Comment: I think you mean "refs/heads" instead of "refs/HEAD", right? Well... when you push to "refs/heads/branch" you're pushing straight to the branch (the same way you push when you use just "branch") but when you push to "refs/for/branch" you're pushing to a "magical" branch that Gerrit assumes you want to create a review for that change. Learn more about that in the "Gerrit Code Review - A Quick Introduction" item of the Gerrit documentation: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-quick.html

Comment: yeah i meant heads only, it was a typo . You are right !!! thnx a lot !!!!